# Como traduzir o termo "enabler"?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução, estrangeirismos

No contexto da psicologia, *enabler* é um personagem que defende, financia, protege, permite e/ou colabora com os comportamentos viciosos ou abusivos de uma pessoa, que, em geral, não seria capaz (daí a origem do termo) de lidar com as consequências dos próprios hábitos:

> While my parents never hit me or sexually abused me, there was a lot of crazy making, ignoring serious problems, us kids feeling like we were entirely on our own, an emotionally abusive father that my enabler mother told us we had to endure.
>
> *Apesar dos meus pais nunca terem me batido ou abusado sexualmente de mim, havia uma quantidade imensa de loucura que fazia com que, ignorando problemas graves, nós, filhos, sentíssemo-nos como se estivéssemos abandonados, [com] um pai emocionalmente abusivo que minha mãe `enabler` nos dizia para aturar.*
>
> <sub>Fonte: [Raised by Narcissists](https://www.reddit.com/r/raisedbynarcissists/comments/4ls0r2/oh_wait_neglect_is_abuse_too/?ref=search_posts), grupo de apoio para vítimas de abuso infantil</sub>

Por extensão, o termo é usado em outros contextos quando na busca de culpados:

> School as an Enabler of Deviant Behavior: In contrast to its constraining effect the school can also serve as a breeding ground for undesired
>   deviant behaviors among students.
>
> *A Escola como `Enabler` de Comportamentos Transgressivos: Em contraste com seu efeito limitador, a escola também pode servir como um solo fértil para comportamentos transgressivos indesejados entre estudantes.*
>
> <sub>Fonte: [ESAYAS, S (2011). *The School and Deviant Behavior: A Case Study* (...).](http://etd.aau.edu.et/bitstream/123456789/734/3/Selam%20Esayas.pdf)</sub>

---

Enfim, que palavras eu poderia usar nestes dois fragmentos para expressar o significado de `enabler`, de forma a deixar clara sua relação com o transtorno?

Comment: Essa definição tem um pouco a ver com o significado que explicou ? Ou é um significado técnico bem mais específico ? http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/enabler

Comment: @Luciano Tem bastante a ver, sim. A primeira delas tem uma falha que é "significant other", já que o "enabler" não precisa ser próximo da vítima (de fato, muitos deles são meros conhecidos). A segunda definição parece ser muito similar. A terceira tem um pouco de opinião embutida, mas também é bastante similar. Só um adendo: "enabler" não é um personagem só nos quadros de vício, mas também nos quadros de abuso e de distúrbios de personalidade.

Comment: Ok. Minha dúvida foi mais para entender, do que contribuir diretamente com uma resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: @Luciano Não tem de quê, sinta-se à vontade para perguntar quantas vezes quiser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neste contexto, acredito que a melhor tradução é **facilitador**. Vide, por exemplo, artigo acadêmico publicado na Revista Brasileira de Enfermagem e indexado pela rede Scielo de textos de caráter científico:

> Uma confusão que pode ocorrer com pessoas próximas
>   e importantes na vida de um alcoolista é o que se chama de
>   **facilitação**. A facilitação é um comportamento que, mesmo
>   tendo boas intenções, serve para proteger o dependente das
>   conseqüências do uso de droga, ou seja, há negação do
>   alcoolismo, trazendo com isso o agravamento da situação.
>   Muitos chefes são **facilitadores** na medida em que acham
>   que não têm nada a ver com isto; tal postura favorece a perda
>   de trabalhadores, uma vez que o desempenho no trabalho e a
>   produtividade são cada vez mais comprometidos.
>
> Fonte: ["O trabalho e o alcoolismo: estudo com trabalhadores"](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0034-71672004000300018)

Comment: Ailton, creio também que *facilitador* é o termo apropriado. Mas uma sugestão: podias incluir uma passagem deste artigo ou outros exemplificando o uso de *facilitador*. A resposta ficaria melhor, porque o leitor teria logo aqui os exemplos; e há ainda a possibilidade de no futuro o link já não funcionar.

Comment: Muito interessante, não havia pensado em pesquisar nos periódicos de enfermagem, onde o uso de _facilitador_ é até razoavelmente comum. No contexto mais geral, _facilitador_ também parece ser compreendido com este sentido: _["O foro privilegiado em si não é criminógeno, mas é um facilitador da corrupção"](http://www.conjur.com.br/2016-mar-30/stf-nao-sabe-julgar-processos-penais-procurador-lava-jato)_

Comment: @Jacinto preciso me habituar a fazer isso. Eu mesmo já me deparei com resposta cujo link não é mais válido. No caso desta resposta, eu ainda esperava encontrar algo que formalizasse esse uso no contexto da saúde mental, e esse artigo do periódico de Enfermagem foi o mais próximo disso. Porém a chance deste link do Scielo sumir e a Revista Brasileira de Enfermagem não ir pra outro lugar é bem pequena. Muito bem vinda a edição!

Comment: Ailton e @Ramon, eu procurei no Google *facilitador abuso*, sem aspas, e encontra-se *facilitador* frequentemente usado no sentido pretendido, no contexto de abuso de crianças, abuso de drogas, etc.

Comment: Mais que isto, @Jacinto: também me interessa que o sentido se estenda para "outros contextos quando na busca de culpados", como o _[facilitador da corrupção](http://www.conjur.com.br/2016-mar-30/stf-nao-sabe-julgar-processos-penais-procurador-lava-jato)_ e _[facilitador ou entrave](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22facilitador+ou+entrave%22)_ (55 resultados, bem mais comum do que eu imaginava).

Answer (score 0):

Nestes contextos traduziria *enabler* como **potenciador**, um vez que nos exemplos descritos os intervenientes ou contextos parecem ser catalisadores que fomentam ou propiciam comportamentos.

Comment: Mas, se eu disser que a mãe da menina é _potenciadora_, não pareço dar a entender que ela tem papel ativo no abuso? A ideia do termo `enabler` é deixar claro que, embora o personagem esteja contribuindo diretamente para a piora do quadro, o comportamento dele por si só não é condenável.

Comment: Penso que potenciador possa ter esse mesmo significado, de algo que fomenta, participa, ou auxilia, mas não necessariamente o unico factor ou o principal contribuinte.

Comment: Duarte e @Ramon, o sentido duma palavra ajusta-se com o uso. O que me parece importante nestes casos é  ver se a palavra já é usada no sentido pretendido. *Facilitador* é (procurem no Google *facilitador* + *abuso*, sem aspas); não procurei *potenciador*, não sei se é.